# How to use condition to get rid of rows in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Person Test  
1 new  
1 new  
1 old  
1 old  
2 new  
2 new  
2 old
```

and I want to get rid of the rows with unequal numbers of test on the new system and the old system. In this case, person 2 is tested 2 times on new and 1 time on old, so I want to get rid of all his data (the last three rows.) How do I achieve this with a large dataset?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the frequency of each unique value for each `person` with `table` and select the groups where the count is the same for all unique values.

This can be done in base R :

```
subset(df, ave(Test, Person, FUN = function(x) length(unique(table(x)))) == 1)

#  Person Test
#1      1  new
#2      1  new
#3      1  old
#4      1  old
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Person) %>% filter(n_distinct(table(Test)) == 1)
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.SD[uniqueN(table(Test)) == 1], Person]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `ave` and `table`.

```
i <- with(df1, ave(Test, Person, FUN = function(x){
  all(table(x) == length(x) %/% 2)
}))
df1[as.logical(i), ]
#  Person Test
#1      1  new
#2      1  new
#3      1  old
#4      1  old
```